# symfony2 empty session id in service

Tags: php, symfony, session, symfony-2.5

I use symfony 2.5, and I have next service for monolog.

```
<?php

namespace Megogo\CoreBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class SessionRequestProcessor
{
    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session
     */
    protected $session;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    private $token;

    public function __construct( Session $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function processRecord(array $record)
    {

        if (null === $this->token) {
            try {
                $this->token = $this->session->getId();
            } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
                $this->token = '????????';
            }

        }
        $record['extra']['token'] = $this->token;

        return $record;
    }
}
```

service.yml

```
services:
    monolog.formatter.session_request:
        class: Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter
        arguments:
            - "[%%datetime%%] [%%extra.token%%] %%channel%%.%%level_name%%: %%message%%\n"

    monolog.processor.session_request:
        class: Megogo\CoreBundle\SessionRequestProcessor
        arguments:  ["@session"]
        tags:
            - { name: monolog.processor, method: processRecord }
```

I get example from official documentation. [Adding a Session/Request Token](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog.html#adding-a-session-request-token)

I have problem, that `$this->session->getId()` return empty string. If I add  `$session->start();`  all works. I can get session id. But this is weird, because in other my services all works without this workaround. And when I make `app/console cache:clear` I have error `Failed to start the session: already started by PHP.`

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I need this as well please

Comment: @JoeYahchouchi Sorry, but no, I didn't solve it :(

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar issue.

I've solved it by adding in a controller

```
$this->get('session')->start();
```

In your case you could simply add following line before you try to get session ID

```
$this->session->start();
```

Don't worry about calling "start()" when session is already started - it will check and simply skip (re)starting it.

Current (2.6) version of Symfony does not have [config property](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#session) which would force session auto_start

Answer (score 0):

Official docs says:

> Symfony sessions are incompatible with php.ini directive **session.auto_start = 1** This directive should be turned off in php.ini, in the webserver directives or in .htaccess.

Maybe try this?